# Getting wrong query generated by Sequelize Assocation

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two table. One is `Order` and second one is `OrderStatus`.
In the orders table `order_status_code` is `foreignKey` that references on `id` to the `OrderStatus` table.
I have below model association definition.

```
 Order.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Order.hasOne(models.OrderItem,{foreignKey: "order_id"}),
    Order.hasOne(models.OrderStatus, {foreignKey: "order_status_code"})
  };
```

I am getting below error:

> Unknown column 'OrderStatus.order_status_code' in 'field list

when I try to eager loading the OrderStatus.

```
const orders = await Order.findAll({
        where: filter,
        include: {
            model: OrderStatus
        }
    })
```

Below is the query that is being shown on the console.

```
SELECT `Order`.`id`, `Order`.`buyer_id`, `Order`.`order_status_code`, `Order`.`order_detail`, `Order`.`order_date`, `Order`.`order_number`, `Order`.`created_at`, `Order`.`updated_at`, `OrderStatus`.`id` AS `OrderStatus.id`, `OrderStatus`.`order_status_code` AS `OrderStatus.order_status_code`, `OrderStatus`.`status` AS `OrderStatus.status`, `OrderStatus`.`created_at` AS `OrderStatus.created_at`, `OrderStatus`.`updated_at` AS `OrderStatus.updated_at` FROM `Orders` AS `Order` LEFT OUTER JOIN `OrderStatuses` AS `OrderStatus` ON `Order`.`order_status_code` = `OrderStatus`.`id` WHERE `Order`.`buyer_id` = 23;
```

I don't know why it is selecting `OrderStatus.order_status_code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by defining `attributes` to select from the included model and It fixed the problem for now.

```
const orders = await Order.findAll({
        where: filter,
        include: {
            model: OrderStatus,
            attributes:["status"]
        }
    })
```